# Site navigation using radio input

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, navigation, radio-button

Short:
I would like to use input type radio in form as a site navigation tool without need of clicking on submit button. Is this possible?

Explanation:
I am using jQuery Mobile library for my GUI and I like how the look of radio input is automatically changed - In this look I want to classify people according to their names and to switch between pages in long output.

[image: The automatic look of page numbers and alphabet letters that I currently have]

My current code i like this:

```
<form action="custmers.php" method="post">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                <input type="radio" name="nav" id="a" value="customers.php?letter=a">
                <label for="a">A</label>
                :
                :
                <input type="radio" name="nav" id="z" value="customers.php?letter=z">
                <label for="z">Z</label>
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

But except of highlighting currently clicked option the page doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work (haven't tested it)
Its still early in the morning... So there is a chance I'm still tired and not thinking properly. Haha

Change your form to

```
<form action="customers.php" id="navigation" method="get">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="radio" name="letter" id="a" value="a">
        <label for="a">A</label>
          :
          :
        <input type="radio" name="letter" id="z" value="z">
        <label for="z">Z</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then add some jquery to your scripts

```
$(function(){
    var $navigation=$('#navigation');
    $navigation.on('change','input[name=letter]',function(){
        $navigation.submit();
        // or to take a more complicated (read: unneccessary)
        // window.location($navigation.attr('action')+'?letter='+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

Do note: you should consider some validation in here. I wont bother mentioning security since you didnt post the rest of your script.